# An approximation of denomiator

Tags: taylor-expansion, rationalising-denominator

I am trying to figure out how to make an approximation of  $\frac{1}{x^a+y}$ to separate the term $x$ and $y$? I have tried to use Taylor expansion, but it also left the same denominator term? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are using a Taylor series (or similar) what value(s) would you like the approximation to be most accurate near? Maybe this link gives you some ideas: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series+1%2F(x%5E2%2By)

Comment: thanks, it gives me some hint.